# How is the distortion matrix determined in weak gravitational lensing?

Tags: gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

**Problem**

For a weak lensing system, with deflection potential $\psi(\theta)$, the distortion matrix is given by $$\vec{A}(\vec{\theta})=\delta_{ij}-\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\theta_i\partial\theta_j}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\kappa-\gamma_1 & -\gamma_2\\-\gamma_2 & 1-\kappa+\gamma_1 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $$\gamma=\gamma_1+i\gamma_2=|\gamma|e^{2i\phi}$$ $$\gamma_1=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_{,11}-\psi_{,22})$$ $$\gamma_2=\psi_{,12}.$$

How are the components of the matrix  A determined? I understand the way in which it is parametrised by 3 numbers (because $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$.)

**My attempt**

I have tried to look further into breaking down the matrix, so looking at the Kronecker delta have seen thaat we must have $\delta_{11}=\delta_{22}=1$ and $\delta_{12}=0$ which is the same as $\delta_{21}$, thus giving a 2x2 identity matrix. It's quite clear then that there must be something like $$A=(1-\kappa)\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}-...,$$ but I am just getting really confused with how everything is determined.